# Why does .at() member function of a vector return a reference instead of an iterator?

Tags: c++, stl

Up until a few days ago I thought all 'position' related member functions of a `vector` returned an `iterator`. I found out recently that while `insert()` and `erase()` functions do indeed return `iterators`, `begin()` and `end()` do so by definition, but functions like `at()`, `front()`, `back()` do not do so, they return a simple reference.

While references make life easier as I would not have to dereference the `iterator` fist, to me it still seems inconsistent that some member functions are returning a reference instead of an iterator. If anything, C++ tries to minimize inconsistencies like this by providing the bare minimum while still maintaining ease in programming.

Comment: Think of `at()` as a safe equivalent of `[]`, which is intended to have equivalent behaviour to using a raw array.

Comment: @BoBTFish that makes sense. But what about front() and back() functions? Their functionality can be easily achieved by using .begin() and .end() appropriately.

Comment: Sure. I don't really see the problem, so I guess this may be too opinion-based for SO. I see that for accessing a single specific element, you get it directly (as a reference). For accessing some portion (possibly all) of the range, you use iterators. I've never seen an issue with this model.

Comment: `front` and `back` are just convenience functions - such a convenience function for `begin() + n` would be fine (let's call it `offset`?), but for now, nobody in standard's committee has yet had the idea, so it does not exist...

Comment: Why do you consider it inconsistent to have two ways of accessing the data ? Maybe you meant redundant ?

Comment: @Aconcagua Well, once you are working with iterators you are working with a different abstraction, assuming you know nothing about the container itself. So you would use the generic [`advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) function.

Comment: These reference returning functions are abstractions implemented for the convenience of developers, and not at the expense of other functionality, so i don't see why they should be removed for the sake of "consistency". After all, the STL library can also be "easily" achieved by writing appropriate vanilla C++...

Comment: @BoBTFish With such a convenience function, one would still be working with the vector and only then get the iterator *already* advanced... It's just about convenience, if using `operator+` or `std::advance` is not of relevance here...

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I used the word inconsistent specifically because it doesn't fit the STL model of containers + algorithms + iterators. Having front(), back(), at() functions might be convenient but it might also trip people like me up when they realise that iterators aren't being returned like one would expect in STL

Comment: @AayushMahajan Iterators exist to solve the problem of having Containers and Algorithms interact. These direct-access functions exist as part of the Containers abstraction, and take no part in the interaction with Algorithms. Perhaps you have don't fully understand that there are multiple interacting concepts which the Standard Library is built from, which is why this seems inconsistent to you. Hmm, I'm going to stop here, this risks getting a bit personal. This is why opinionated topics are considered off-topic.

Comment: @AayushMahajan : iterators are just one component of the STL - the STL is not centered around that one component. If you ask why there's a need for functions like `front` and `back` if there already are similar functions defined returning an iterator, then convenience is one answer. But more practically, these extra functions are directly used to support container adapters like [`queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue).

Comment: @BoBTFish I'm aware that iterators are used to abstract the container away so algorithms don't need to be implemented again and again. I still like to ask provenance based questions like these here because some one or the other in this community knows how some obscure detail of C++ came into being. And no hard feelings ofcourse, I have no shame in admitting that I have a lot to learn yet!

Comment: @AayushMahajan: If front() returned an iterator it would not be any different from begin().

Answer (score 9):

`at` method is from the group of common container methods called 'Element access', those return reference, pointers.
There is another group of common container methods called 'Iterators', those return iterators.
It is clear, simple and well-known design decision for the standard library.

#### Element access

- `at`: access specified element with bounds checking
- `operator[]`: access specified element
- `front`: access the first element
- `back`: access the last element
- `data` direct access to the underlying array

#### Iterators

- `begin`/`cbegin` returns an iterator to the beginning
- `end`/`cend` returns an iterator to the end
- `rbegin`/`crbegin` returns a reverse iterator to the beginning
- `rend`/`crend` returns a reverse iterator to the end

In the iterator concept, elements within iterator range are accessed through [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) method of STD. This would work for `InputIterator`s, for BST, list, vectors, etc., of course with different complexity.

Answer (score 1):

`begin()`, `end()`, `insert()`, `erase()`, etc. are methods that work on the vectors' sequence of elements itself, while `operator []`, `at()`, `front()`, and `back()` are methods that access concrete elements of this sequence. I don't really see an inconsistency here. They exist for all sequence containers and they always do conceptually the same thing. Sure, you could implement something like `front()` and `back()` yourself, nothing keeps you from doing so. They are *by definition* equivalent to dereferencing `begin()` and `prev(end())` respectively. They exist for convenience. Depending on how far you want to go, `std::vector` itself exists just for convenience…

Answer (score 0):

The abstraction that the Standard Template Library presents is **sequences**, **iterators**, and **algorithms**. Container are one way of creating and managing sequences, but they are not the only way. For example, an input stream can be used as a sequence, by creating a `std::istream_iterator`. But things like `int i; double d; std::cin >> i >> d;` would be rather awkward to write if `std::cin` **only** defined an iterator-based interface. Same thing for containers: they're useful in contexts other than iteration, and they define interfaces appropriate to their general uses; one of those uses is as a sequence for STL algorithms, but there are other uses, too.